# MySQL: BETWEEN .. how to check for a range?

Tags: mysql, range, between

i need to write a query for the following situation:

3 columns: "box", "in", "out" (box is an integer, in and out are dates)

i need something to test if from the "in" date to the "out" date (the period between these dates), a certain box id number has been given already.

i thought to do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl` WHERE `box` = '#' AND ***period*** BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
```

(i know BETWEEN doesn't work this way ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)), but it was just to give you an idea...)

***period*** = the new dates that i'm tryin to register in the database

so, if the query returns '0' i know i can assign this box # in those dates, if not i know i can't. i'm stucked here since last week!! X(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want either:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE box = '#' AND
    `in` =< 'date1' AND out >= 'date1'
    OR `in` =< 'date2' AND out >= 'date2'
```

or

```
SELECT ... AND
    period BETWEEN `in` AND out
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer...i had some issue with your version (ex: "=<" is "<=" and then i had to youse some parentheses)
here's how i solved:

SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `box` = '#' AND

(`in` < '2013-03-20' AND `out` > '2013-03-20'
OR `in` < '2013-03-21' AND `out` > '2013-03-21')